# c++: how to read from and write to a folder

Tags: c++, file-io

I've found tons of examples on file IO, but nothing with folders?

anyone have a quick example?

Note: I'm on *.nix

Comment: "folder" is a dumbed down name for a directory. What do you mean by "writing to a folder"? Creating a file to put in it?

Comment: yes. I just want to be organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be reading and writing to folders - that's the file system's job.  If you want to read a directory, take a look at [opendir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/opendir.html) and friends.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Boost FileSystem](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at opendir, readdir, closedir, etc. functions.